# accessing specific values from Objects in angular 2

Tags: angular, object, angular2-services, angular2-directives

i have a function in my angular 2 project

```
this.fetchedData=  this._visitService.getchartData().toPromise();
console.log("WORKING I HOPE0", this.fetchedData)`
```

which gives the output:

```
WORKING I HOPE0 
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state:true
__zone_symbol__value:Array(2)
0:{date: "2018, 03, 14", value: 11}
1:{date: "2018, 03, 15", value: 1}
length:2
__proto__:Array(0)
__proto__:Object`
```

Is it possible to access `__zone_symbol__value` to get it whole as an object or even just retrieve data from it. I tried using `console.log("WORKING I HOPE0", this.fetchedData.__zone_symbol__value)` but it doesn't seem to work. I am not looking for any alternate way of doing it. So if I wanted to know if its possible or not and why or why not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should do it like :

```
this._visitService.getchartData().toPromise().then(data => {
    this.fetchedData = data;
    console.log(data);
})
```

---

**For your queries as per the comment , try this :**

```
this._visitService.getchartData().toPromise().then(data => {
    this.fetchedData = data;
    console.log(data);
    this.processFetchedData(); // call the function once this.fetchedData is initialized
})

processFetchedData(){
    console.log(this.fetchedData); // check the console
}
```

Comment: Well I tried that and I know it works but after that the `this.fetchData` is available only inside that specific function only , but i want to be able to access it outside of it inside another function.

Comment: nope , it will available outside of the function also as you are assigning it to this.fetchData , `{{ fetchData | json }}` put this line in your template side and you will get the idea , it will be available only when it intialised ,

Comment: I dont want the data in the template i want it in the code.

Comment: @AtulStha , you can call the second function from then , this way the second function will be called once `this.fetchedData` is intialised

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to know 'why' aspect:-
You have to first wait for the promise to resolve. In the resolving function's success handler, you will get the data. Right now, the "fetchedData" variable stores the promise, it will have only Promise specific functionality and "NOT" the actual data.
Upon its resolve, as below, you can retrieve the data and do the required parsing.

Actual code which will work is the one given by @Vivek Doshi above, using the 'then' function.

You can add specific success/failure handlers as follows (if u want it separately):-

```
var promise = serviceCall.toPromise();
promise.success( (data) => this.fetchedData = data );
promise.error( (err) => console.log(err.message) );
```

Answer (score 2):

A *Promise* handles a single event when an asynchronous operation completes or fails.

- It returns a single value.
- It's not cancellable.
- It's provide a readable code with try/catch and async/await.

You should wait for the promise to resolve, so this is what you need:

```
this._visitService.getchartData().toPromise()
  .then(response => {
    this.fetchedData = response;
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
```

If your response comes from an http call:

```
this._visitService.getchartData().toPromise()
  .then(response => {
    var json = response.json();
    this.fetchedData = json;
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue as I've been refactoring code to use async/await, and in this occasion forgot to prefix the function call with await.

Adding in e.g.

```
async MyFunction() {

    this.fetchedData = await this._visitService.getchartData().toPromise();

}
```

may do the trick, if this was your intention (it was, in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your object first before assign the object to them.

```
this._visitService.getchartData().toPromise().then(data => {
    this.fetchedData = {}; //initialize object
    this.fetchedData = data;
    console.log(data);
})
```